# How to 'derefence' an object in Java

Tags: java

```
class DogOwner {
    Dog dog;

    DogOwner(Dog dog) {
        this.dog = dog;
    }
}

class Dog {
    int age;

    Dog(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}

DogOwner peter = new DogOwner(new Dog(2));
Dog max = peter.dog;
max.age = 3;

System.out.println(peter.dog.age); // 3
```

How can I retreive `max` from `peter` without `max` being a reference to the `Dog` owned by `peter`? In other words, I would like to be able to set `max`'s age to 3 without `peter`'s `Dog` being changed.

Comment: But `max` *is* `peter`'s `Dog`. You need a *new* `Dog`.

Comment: My head's spinning...interesting twist...

Comment: Are you looking for a clone?

Comment: @Iamnotmaynard: Yes, I am

Comment: Sorry, you can't [dereference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) a Java reference.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I know Dave, I will explain my situation. I need to be able to edit `max`'s properties, while being able to compare these to the original afterwards. I could just define all properties, though I feel like that's not the clean way.

Comment: @aioobe: That's exactly why I wrote `dereference` with ''. Since I did not know a better term.

Comment: Emm, in class *Dog* the constructor receives only one parameter, but when you create *DogOwner* you do: `new DogOwner(new Dog("Max", 2));`?? Probably you missed `String name`. The correct constructor would be: `public Dog(String name, int age) { this.name = name; this.age = age; }`. Correct it...

Comment: @informatik01: You're right, result of changing the example. I thought it would be weird to change the `Dog`'s name, so I added the age and didn't completely remove name.

Comment: @Aquillo It's OK. Sometimes it happens when in a hurry ))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either have to clone `peter.dog`, or create a new instance based on it.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was looking for this function. I did not know the name though. Will accept asap.

Answer (score 3):

Implement `clone` method for Dog:

```
class Dog implements Cloneable
{
  public Dog clone()
  {
      try{
           return (Dog)super.clone();
      } catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex)
      {
           // should not happen
           return null;
      }
  }

}
```

Then the usage can look like:

```
Dog max = peter.dog.clone();
max.age = 3;
```

Comment: Since NilsH beat you to it, I will accept his answer. Since you took the time to come with an example, I will upvote :)

Comment: Note that with this technique, you are essentially using 'Object.clone()', which will create a copy of the object with all primitive values the same, and all references pointing to the same external object.  Thus, if `Dog` contained a reference to a mutable object, this clone technique would be inadequate.  The external object would need to be cloned as well, and the references in the cloned `Dog` updated to the copies.

Comment: @BaileyS: You're right. Thanks for make a note of it. Though in my case, that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `peter.dog` and `max` to evolve independently, they must be separate instances, which means you mus copy `peter.dog` instead of just assigning it to max.

You can create a copying constructor :

```
Dog(Dog otherDog) {
    this.age = otherDog.age;
}
```

and then

```
Dog max = new Dog(peter.dog);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

```
Dog max = peter.dog;
```

Instead of this line, you can *deep-copy* `peter.dog` and then assign the copy to `max`, you are done, you can manipulate it freely.

Answer (score 1):

`max` is *already* a reference to `peter.dog`. You can't just call Peter's dog "Max" and take the man's dog away! If you don't want him to be Peter's dog, you're going to have to get a new dog...

```
Dog max = new Dog(peter.dog.age);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DogOwner peter = new DogOwner(new Dog("Max", 2)); //This creates two new objects
Dog max = peter.dog;//This sets a reference to one of those objects, somewhat indirectly
```

Because you have only one `Dog` object in your heap, you cannot possibly have the dog pointed to by the `peter` reference be a different dog from the one pointed to by the reference `max`. You must create a new `Dog` by either cloning `peter`'s dog or creating a new one wholesale.

Comment: If you enlighten me as to how you're confused, I will attempt to clarify.